# How to dynamically insert <a href> in the image caption?

Tags: gallery, captions

So, below is the Wordpress default generated code for a gallery item:

```
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-203 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
    <dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
                <a href='image url'><img width="150" height="120" src="thumbnail image" class="attachment-thumbnail"/></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>Caption Text</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

What I need, is to surround the caption text with the image url, so when the user clicks on the caption it will open the big image, like this:

```
<dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><a href="image url">Caption Text</a></dd>
```

I know I can do this via image gallery with a href in the caption text, but the site is for a client and I want to be done dynamically.

I also found that this can be done in media.php (via functions.php), but I don't know how...

I hope I've made myself clear :)

Answer (score 2):

That markup is created by the [`caption` shortcode](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L629). If you look at the the source for that shortcode you will see this:

```
 // Allow plugins/themes to override the default caption template.
 $output = apply_filters('img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content);
 if ( $output != '' )
  return $output;
```

That means that you can hook a function into `img_caption_shortcode` and completely hijack the `caption` shortcode. So copy the code from line ~643 to the end of the function, insert that into your own function, hook that to `img_caption_shortcode`, and make whatever changes you need to get the markup you want.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but I was thinking that I should alter this code: return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
656         . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';

Comment: Yes, you should alter that code, but you should do so the way I explained and not by hacking Core files.

Comment: Ok, as you see I know where to modify, but the problem is I don't know how, could you please provide me the code? Of course I will not alter the media.php, I will insert the code into functions.php. thank you.

Comment: I will see what I can do a little later